# initState() not show in Autosuggetion

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I try to override `initState()` inside `_SplashScreenState`,  but it not show in suggestions list, i try invalid catches/Restart too.

```
import 'package:coupfferapp/screen/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();

  }

   class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {



@override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
_checkLoginSession().then((status) {
  _navigateToHome();
  });
}

Future<bool> _checkLoginSession() async {
await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 5000), () {});
return true;
   }

void _navigateToHome() {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()));
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
  //            Opacity(
  //                    opacity: .9,
  //                    child: Image.asset('images/splash.png', fit: 
   BoxFit.cover)),
        Shimmer.fromColors(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(
                "Mayur",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 90.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Calistoga',
                    shadows: <Shadow>[
                      Shadow(
                          blurRadius: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          offset: Offset.fromDirection(120, 12))
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
            baseColor: Colors.orange,
            highlightColor: Colors.red)
      ],
     ),
    ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: did `initState` get called?

Comment: It may sound silly but I had this problem because I was typing `initState` after the class properties, but right above a property getter, and I wasn't getting any suggestions. I noticed that below the getter, right above the first method, it was indeed working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I have just call my initState function from right above the build function. Let nothing comes between your initState() and build function.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? buildAuthScreen() : buildUnAuthScreen();
  }
```

Comment: I had to put an @override and then the auto suggestion came up. until then there was no luck

Answer (score 1):

you need to type right above the build method otherwise the snippet won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you have it in suggestion, maybe you put it in the wrong sort. It has to be outside the build function:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes i try outside the build functions , but no luck

Comment: Hm, so I copied your code, placed it in a basic .dart file and put @override in, then I typed 'in' and auto suggestion brought the rest. Can you maybe provide more code? the issue should be somewhere else then

Comment: Had same issue: Just moved it a bit and right above the "Build" method and with copy paste it worked. Auto suggestion doesnt work anway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sometimes it does not show you the overridden methods maybe you have type initial letters and click Ctrl+Space for windows and Cmd +space for Mac  which forces it to find the methods. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to start typing the letter *i*, and I can see the `initState() { ... }` shortcut. This shortcut appears even when I don't type it directly above the build method. Screenshot taken with Android Studio 2022.1.1

[image: The init state shortcut showing after typing the letter 'i']